# Can't log in locally, but SSH works

Tags: linux

I can't log in to the console locally. After logging in, it flashes back to the login prompt. If given a wrong password, it will pause for a couple seconds then give the standard "Login incorrect" response. It affects all accounts: root, my user account, and a new account I made to debug the issue. I can log in via SSH perfectly fine.

/etc/inittab: http://pastie.org/3737435

auth.log:

```
Apr  6 03:09:01 [hostname] /usr/sbin/crond[1122]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr  6 03:09:01 [hostname] /USR/SBIN/CROND[1122]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Are there any messages in `/var/log/secure`?  Are your consoles listed in `/etc/securetty`?  What distribution is this?

Comment: Look at pam.  Not sure what, but maybe that is a messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling. It was too tricky to figure out because no errors were logged. Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions.

Comment: You poor soul!  Actually the problem was most likely related to the getty crashing or similar, especially given the lack of errors.

Answer (score 2):

First, gather information by inspecting `/var/log/messages` for any information that may be there.

Next, narrow the scope of your problem down. Log in to SSH and change the interactive shell for a user and see if that changes anything. Try `csh` or `zsh` - anything, really. I've heard of SSH not honoring .bashrc files, so perhaps somehow there is a `TMOUT=0` variable in there or some other logic that kicks you out immediately (but SSH connections aren't honoring it, which is possible).

Comment: SSHd might be overriding the shell too, "fixing" a broken shell entry in /etc/passwd

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, those are the only 2 lines logged. I changed the shell in /etc/passwd to sh first then nano for the hell of it. It worked in SSH, but not on the console. There is no .bashrc. Single user mode works.